# react-big-calendar import failing for css

Tags: css, reactjs, calendar

I have the react big calendar working but the css import is  failing. 
The documentation says:

Styles can be found at: react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css, and should be included on the page with the calendar component.

I've seen it imported w/ BigCalendar in other examples but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
import '/react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import Month from './Month';
import React from 'react';
import Showfeed from './Showfeed';
```

How do I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: What are your loaders for webpack? You need to tell webpack about css.

Comment: I am using Brunch not Webpack but your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just needed to add this to my brunch-config.js file.

```
npm: {
  styles: {
  'react-big-calendar': ['lib/css/react-big-calendar.css']
  }
},
```

If your using this solution you can delete the import. You don't need it.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who stumbles on this issue:

OP is actually quite close. The import line has an additional slash at the front. If you're importing react-big-calendar as a node module the line here:

**import '/react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';**

Should be:

**import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';**

Answer (score 4):

Don't know what exactly problem you are facing. But To include css,you can  try this. Not tested, but it should work.

```
require('react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css');
```

2. If above not works, copy the react-big-calendar.css file CSS and paste to your own css file.

Comment: It tried your suggestion. Still not working. 
Error is... 
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css' from 'components/Calendar.jsx'(…)

Comment: Are you able to check CSS file inside node_modules?

Comment: Just checked. The file is there. Seems like the path is correct. It's just not finding it.

Comment: So, than only option left is include calendar  CSS in inde.html.                          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css"/>

Comment: I added the suggested require statement to my component and it worked

Answer (score 1):

try to add this CDN to your-react-project-root/public/index.html

`<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-big-calendar@0.19.0/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import '../lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
```

but first validate that the file exst in the path/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
```