# When implementing react big calendar or any react package, the css is not showing in shopify app. how can I go around this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app, react-big-calendar

I am implementing React-big-calendar, but the css doesn't seem to show up.
I am getting a plain html style vertical calendar without css.
Is the css being overidden in shopify?

This is the code I am working with

```
import React from "react";
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
// import 'react-big-calendar/lib/sass/styles' ;
import moment from "moment"; // Import moment here

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

const events = [
  {
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() + 1)),
    title: "Sample Event",
  },
  // Add more events here
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={events}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: This is the output]

This is what i am expecting
https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/story/about-big-calendar--page

Comment: Is it related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837152/react-big-calendar-import-failing-for-css

Comment: I saw this question but, the solutions given in that question dont seem to work. As i am working on the shopify environment.

Answer (score 0):

You've done this correctly. The question then becomes, how are you bundling your code? For instance, in storybook I have to use one of their presets, added to the `addons` config in `main.js`, in order to properly process my css (or, in my case, my sass). Your bundler configuration will determine if you css is inlined in the js file (dynamically put in the head of your document), or if it generates an external stylesheet that you must manually include.